# cannot use jquery selector on cloned items

Tags: jquery

Is this normal?

```
// Put testimonials in slides
        var testimonialEls = $("#block-testimonials").children();
        var testimonialCache = testimonialEls.clone();
        //testimonialEls.remove();
        var testimonials = [];

        console.dir(testimonialCache.siblings("article").not(".featured,.featured-wide"));
        console.dir(testimonialEls.siblings("article").not(".featured,.featured-wide"));
```

testimonialEls works testimonialCache returns 0.

I cannot use jquery selector on cloned item?

http://jsfiddle.net/MUREY/2/

Comment: "Is this normal?" Ya, cloning a specific element doesn't clone all siblings/ascendants nor all the DOM... Maybe you should clone siblings too or whatever you are trying to do here which no one is aware of. EDIT: clone create a copy of element, this copy is not part of DOM so you cannot try to target any sibling. Maybe just clone the parent instead so that all children will be part of cloned element

Comment: @A.Wolff there is nothing particularly tricky in my case: http://jsfiddle.net/MUREY/

Comment: You want to use `filter()` here, not `find()`  http://jsfiddle.net/MUREY/3/

Comment: Updated the answer, then noticed your comment. ) Yes, using `filter` is also an option.

Comment: @A.Wolff I didn't know filter() looks awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is cloned with all its children - but not with any of its siblings (that's kind of obvious, I suppose). Quoting the doc:

> The `.clone()` method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes.

What you actually need to do is to clone the 'root' section ('#block-testimonials', in your case), then check for either its direct children - or descendants, whichever suits your case better.

```
// Put testimonials in slides
var testimonialEls = $("#block-testimonials");
var testimonialCache = testimonialEls.clone();

console.dir(testimonialCache.find("article").not(".featured,.featured-wide"));
console.dir(testimonialEls.find("article").not(".featured,.featured-wide"));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rDj5j/). As alternative, you can store the leaf elements only, then check the required ones with [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var testimonialEls = $("#block-testimonials").children();
// ...
console.dir(testimonialEls.filter("article").not(".featured,.featured-wide"));
```

... that'll also give you the same result. But if you need to store `article` elements only in that cache of yours, set these restrictions explicitly:

```
var testimonialEls = $("#block-testimonials").children('article');
// ...
console.dir(testimonialCache.not(".featured,.featured-wide"));
```

Now checking for `article` is obviously redundant - there will be no other elements in that cache, that's why `.filter()` call is no longer required.

Comment: Please add the HTML structure you work with to the question, so it'll be possible to create a fiddle illustrating possible approaches to solve the key problem.

Comment: @salivan what is the purpose of trying `find()` regarding your question? Please post relevant HTML markup too!

Comment: I also need to delete child elements, and keep original container. This means I've recreate it, or use another selector to delete children.

Comment: @salivan Just empty the container then: `$("#block-testimonials").clone().empty()` ?! But as IDs must be unique on document context, change ID of cloned element or better, don't use IDs at all here

Comment: @salivan Updated the answer yet again. BTW, that starts to look as XY problem: have you described what you really want to do (and not only how you want to do it) in the original question, it'd be answered far faster. )

Comment: @raina77ow Ya, typical XY problem. Seems ike OP wants indeed: `var $cloned = $("#block-testimonials").clone().find(".featured,.featured-wide").remove();` But still OP has to face duplicate IDs, maybe following question, who knows... ;)